# MATLAB Create Variable names for column vector elements

Tags: matlab

I have a double column vector as follows:

```
[1;NaN;NaN;2;NaN;NaN;3;NaN;NaN;]
```

What I'd like to do is create a string variable name on the NaN elements that follow the numbers. For example, I'd like my final vector to look like this:

```
[1;wd1;wd1;2;wd2;wd2;3;wd3;wd3]
```

Can anyone help out? Thanks!

Comment: Your initial vector is of type int[] and `NaN` is compatible with that. A random string is not. So there are follow up questions on what you ask: Is it ok to change that type? For example to use cells instead? Is there any significance on the "string variable name" or all you want to do is replace `NaN`s with specific strings? Finally, is this a pattern that between the number 1 and the next number 2 all `NaN`s should be converted to `wd1`?

Comment: I'm ok with changing the type to cells. The significance of the names is dependent on the pattern. Per the aray, we have numerals 1,2,3 with NaNs in between. The objective is to be able to convert all the NaNs in between to the corresponding number, so it would be [1,wd1,wd1,2,wd2,wd2,3,wd3,wd3].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want something like this:

```
b = num2cell(a);

numberPostfix = 0; %in case the first element is NaN
for i = 1:numel(b)
    if( isnan(b{i}) )
        b{i} = ['wd' num2str(numberPostfix)];
    else
        numberPostfix = b{i};
    end
end
```

For input vector

```
a = (1:20)';
a(3:4) = NaN;
a(12:18) = NaN;
```

this will result in

```
b = {1;2;'wd2';'wd2';5;6;7;8;9;10;11;'wd11';'wd11';'wd11';'wd11';'wd11';'wd11';'wd11';19;20}
```